# Ruby string array to hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

In Ruby how do you convert an array to a hash?
I have an array like this

```
people = [
  {"name":"Sam","year":"21"},
  {"name":"cole","partition":"20"},
  {"name":"bart","year":"21"}
]
```

I want to put this array of in a hash like below so I can check who is 21:

```
{
  person1 => {"name"=>"Sam","year"=>"21"},
  person2 => {"name"=>"cole","partition"=>"20"},
  person3 => {"name"=>"bart","year"=>"21"}
}
```

How can I convert this array of to a hash? And how do i check who is 21?

Comment: I'm unclear on the reasoning here: there's no reason to put it in a hash "so" you can check who is 21. You have all the information you need in the array of hashes. Not saying you don't need (or want) it in a hash for some *other* reason, but you certainly don't for the reason stated.

Comment: Further to @Dave's point, how could you possibly make use of the keys in the hash? They differ only by the digits at the end of their names. You could extract the digits from a key, and then convert them to an integer. That would allow you to extract the key's value from the array, but you already have that value from the hash. Alternatively, you could start with an offset into the array, then construct the associated hash key, which would give you the value of that key, but you already have that from the array. Why do you want the hash? It seems to have no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it happens to be spelled "people" ;)

Since the keys `person1`, `person2`, etc. need to be generated, I would loop through your original array, placing each element into a new hash with an appropriate key:

```
people_hash = {}

people.each_with_index do |person, index|
    next unless person[:year] == 21 # This will skip any element that doesn't have an :age of 21

    people_hash["person#{index + 1}"] = person
end

people_hash
#=> {"person1"=>{:name=>"Sam", :year=>"21"}, "person2"=>{:name=>"cole", :partition=>"20"}, "person3"=>{:name=>"bart", :year=>"21"}}
```

The `each_with_index` method will loop through each element of the array, but will also provide the current index of the element, so that we can use it for the hash keys. I've used string interpolation to create the hash keys - since you wanted to start at 1, I've added 1 to the index each time.

Comment: You can use `each_with_object({}).with_object(1)` to get rid of `people_hash` and `index + 1`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma while I personally prefer using handy methods like that, I think they're harder to understand for a beginner, especially if they come from other languages with much smaller standard libs. Also I'm sure you meant .with_index(1), as in your own answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `each_with_object` to iterate over "peaple", and assign to a new hash the current element using as a key the prefix *person* plus the index of the current element (person).

```
peaple
  .each_with_object({})
  .with_index(1) do |(person, hash), index|
    hash["person#{index}"] = person
  end

# {"person1"=>{:name=>"Sam", :year=>"21"},
#  "person2"=>{:name=>"cole", :partition=>"20"},
#  "person3"=>{:name=>"bart", :year=>"21"}}
```

---

Another version just out of curiosity would be to create an array of strings with the same length of "peaple", having as values the prefix "person" plus its index plus 1. Zipping that with the current value and invoking `to_h` on it gives the same result:

```
Array.new(peaple.length) { |i| "person#{i + 1}" }.zip(peaple).to_h
```

---

If the idea is getting who's 21 by using the "year" key, then you can select those elements with year 21 and mapping then their names:

```
peaple
  .select { |person| person[:year] == "21" }
  .map { |person| person[:name] }
# ["Sam", "bart"]
```